# Can you browse a running VoltDB database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, voltdb

I have been using MySQL for years and have decided that for a new project I'd like to use something newer liker Volt DB.

I have read all the documentation on the Volt DB website and although it mentions a web client for viewing the structure it doesn't say if there is a way of viewing data live in the database.

Hoping for a web based client like phpMyAdmin or maybe a desktop client like Navicat (Windows) / Sequal (OSX).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VoltDB includes a web interface called Web Studio on port 8080 by default, that provides a SQL interface with tabular result formatting.  You could use this to select, insert, update, or delete records through SQL statements or by calling stored procedures.

You can also connect to VoltDB using desktop tools that can connect using the JDBC driver, such as SQuirreL.  We are working on an ODBC driver in the next few months that will enable a wider choice of desktop tools to connect.